# Set BottomSheetDialogFragment height to full screen

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

How do I make a bottomSheet take up the full height of the screen? Setting the peek height has no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
bottomSheetDialogFragment.getDialog().setOnShowListener((dialog) ->
{
    final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = (BottomSheetDialog)dialog;
    final FrameLayout bottomSheet = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
    if (bottomSheet != null)
    {
        final BottomSheetBehavior<View> behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        behavior.setPeekHeight(30000); // no effect, bottom sheet does not span entire height of screen
    }
});
```

BottomSheet Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <!-- rest of layout not shown -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottomSheetHandle"
        tools:layout_height="48dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: why not you use simple dialoge with full screen with bottom to top animation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make BottomSheetDialog match parent height (full screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57769252/how-can-i-make-bottomsheetdialog-match-parent-height-full-screen)

Answer (score 4):

You could get the metrics to have access to the height of the screen in pixels and use that reference to set the height of your bottomsheet.

*Get Metrics*

```
val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
requireActivity().windowManager?.defaultDisplay?.getMetrics(metrics)
```

*Set state and peekHeight of dialog*

```
bottomSheetDialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
bottomSheetDialog.behavior.peekHeight = metrics.heightPixels
```

*Set height of your view, notice how we are setting this height as the same of the peekHeight of the dialog. I found this the best way when you want a single size for your BottomSheetDialog*

```
bottomSheet.layoutParams.height = metrics.heightPixels
bottomSheet.requestLayout()
```

Answer (score 2):

at first inside `onCreateDialog`

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    ...
    bottomSheetBehavior?.skipCollapsed = true
    bottomSheetBehavior?.peekHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
    bottomSheetBehavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    return bottomSheet
}
```

afterward, use this on start method

```
/**
 * to make sheet height full screen
 * */
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    requireActivity().windowManager?.defaultDisplay?.getMetrics(metrics)
    binding.rootContainer.layoutParams.height = metrics.heightPixels
    binding.rootContainer.requestLayout()
}
```

I hope it works fine because it work correctly with me ;)

Answer (score 2):

> to accomplish that you can set match_parent to layout params of bottom
> sheet like this:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
                    val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)
                    dialog.setOnShowListener {
                
                        val bottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
                        val parentLayout =
                            bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
                        parentLayout?.let { it ->
                            val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(it)
                            setupFullHeight(it)
                            behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                        }
                    }
                    return dialog
                }
                
                private fun setupFullHeight(bottomSheet: View) {
                    val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
                    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
                }
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers. It would be awesome if you add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// add this code into your class

    @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            Dialog dialog = getDialog();
            View bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            if (dialog != null) {
        
                bottomSheet.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            }
            View view = getView();
            view.post(() -> {
                View parent = (View) view.getParent();
                CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) (parent).getLayoutParams();
                CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
                BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = (BottomSheetBehavior) behavior;
                bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(view.getMeasuredHeight());
                ((View)bottomSheet.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution that worked for me. No need to calculate screen height and all that.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    val parentLayout = dialog?.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
    parentLayout?.let { bottomSheet ->
        val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
        behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }
}
```